# Flutter_Unity_Widget: Failure to initialize, Your hardware does not support this application

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop an entire screen in a flutter project using unity with Flutter_Unity_Widget.
I've followed the package installation instructions at pub.dev "https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget"
but when I run the applications it pops up a window with some errors:
[screenshot for emulator after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuzIy.png)

```
E/Unity   ( 5165): Failed to load 'libmain.so'
E/Unity   ( 5165): 
E/Unity   ( 5165): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.flutter_unity_app-H-CtYDrgxEULJH5uT-8PqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.flutter_unity_app-H-CtYDrgxEULJH5uT-8PqQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.flutter_unity_app-H-CtYDrgxEULJH5uT-8PqQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libmain.so"
E/Unity   ( 5165): Your hardware does not support this application.
```

and I can't handle this error.
versions:
unity: 2021.1.4f1
flutter_unity_widget: ^4.1.0
enulator: Nexus 6 API 28 android pie 9

Answer (score 0):

Unity with emulator is usually painful way to develop. Try to find a real device. Because you have to export your unity as library correctly. First install to your device, then export as library. Do you have same errors with real device? Even you successfully install to your device, there is a warning with the [widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) you use.

> Note: Supports only Unity 2019.4.3 or later. UnityFramework does not support emulator.